# SUMIF only for last condition row

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a spreadsheet where I need to total values using a `SUMIF` function and record that total in another column, but I only want it to record that total for the last instance of a value in the column.

For example, the `11,629` is only shown for the last instance of `103`, etc.

| ItemKey | Amount | Subtotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1,213 |  |
| 103 | 951 |  |
| 103 | 10,656 |  |
| 121 | 435 |  |
| 100 | 6,214 |  |
| 103 | 22 | 11,629 |
| 121 | 9,753 |  |
| 100 | 343 | 7,770 |
| 121 | 2,805 |  |
| 121 | 497 | 13,490 |

I have a SUMIF function that works but populates all rows.  I need to be able to record the formula in every row, but only have it display something for the last instance.

I guess I need something like an `IF(<some way to determine last instance>=True, SUMIF(abcde), "")`, I just don't know how to determine the last instance.  What can I do to put this in place?

Maybe a `COUNTIF` to count instances from current row to the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution. See attached screenshot from Google sheets.

[image]

Array formula in F4

```
=IF(MAX(IF($D$4:$D$13=D4,ROW($D$4:$D$13),0))=ROW(D4),SUMIFS($E$4:$E$13,$D$4:$D$13,D4),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an array formula.  This step is important, the formula will only work correctly when it's an Array Formula.

Now drag it down up to the intended rows.

For each cell it returns the MAX row number from all rows where the value in D reflects down below and if it matches with the current row number, it's the last entry, IF true SUMIFS formula or whatever works for you. Else nothing, blank basically.

Note that I have used SUMIFS using D column as condition rather than SUMIF.

Comment: This worked, thank you.  I had forgotten about array formulas, so my own attempts were not getting the desired result.  This is perfect - much appreciated.